# Changing a value from float64 to String to double. Will the final value change?

Tags: java, python, casting

I am generating a number in the type of "float64" in pythong. It can be negative numbers as well. 
`np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=dims), dtype='float64')`

Then I iterate the list and write the each value `x` to a text file as a String.

```
with open(simulated_data_file, 'a') as data_file_writer:
    data_file_writer.write(str(x)+"\n")
```

Now I read this as a String and converts it to double in Java using `Double.parseDouble(inputFeatureStringArray[i])`

I want to know if there are any circumstances where the initial value generated in python will be different in Java.

Comment: first, all numbers in python are arbitrary precision , or "Doubles". second, Java isn't reading a number, it's reading a string of digits which you then convert to a number.

Comment: Why does this have an upvote!?!?!

Comment: Yes assume I am doing what you said just now. My question was would the number I had in python be different when I read it finally as a double in Java once it has gone through the process? If you had already answered that question I did not get it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, all numbers are arbitrary precision in Python. This has interesting consequences sometimes, but probably not here.

Second, I would like you to re-examine your question: "if I write a number to a text file in Python, will I get the same number back in Java?".

You are generating a number by some means in Python. When you tell Python to open a file for writing in text mode, any subsequent writes to that buffer explicitly require a string (or bytes-ish) object as an argument.

Now you have a text file containing an ASCII or UTF-8 string of digits representing a number.

When Java opens this file for reading, it likely returns a string (or bytes-ish) object. In order to use this string as a number in Java, you will need to use Java's version of `atoi`, which will try to parse the string as a number literal.

TL;DR: your question has nothing to do with numbers and the language-specific `sizeof` whatever, just to do with strings. It's up to you to ensure Python writes text in a way Java can read (not that hard, I assure you).

If you want to write a `word` or bytes-ish object representing a number to a file object as a bytes object: that is, the literal binary representation of a number (which will not result in a text file), then you may encounter some issues, because all Python numbers are, as stated, BigIntegers, essentially.